# Iam facing system.stringexception: String length exceeds maximum: 6000000

Tags: visualforce-component

Iam trying to upload a file using  vf custom component on attachment using Remoteaction method. Iam unable to upload file morethan  4.3mb. Is it possible to upload morethan 20mb using vf custom component.

Answer (score 3):

In order to upload a file larger than 4.3MB or so, at which point you run into this exception, you should use the [Chatter API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_input.htm) to upload a file as large as you need, up to 2 GB in size. There is no way to construct a 20 MB file in Apex code without running in to one or more governor limits.

Comment: when calling through Remoteaction method. Its getting timeout and uploading only 4.3mb